# How do you forward HTTP URL request to ip address + port?

Tags: macos, networking, dns

How do I redirect requests to google.com to 192.123.123.1:8000. Is this even possible? I can't seem to find a way to redirect to a particular port number.

Comment: dns has absolutely nothing to do with port numbers. It deals only with IP addresses. You can make a request to google.com go to your IP address, but DNS can do NOTHING to change the port number being used. That's not DNS's job.

Answer (score 0):

You need something that speaks HTTP or HTTPS, e.g., a web server, to do HTTP or HTTPS protocol-level redirects to different servers and/or ports.